# Do you need to install a GPU on a non-integrated graphics board

Tags: amd-ryzen

Does a board without integrated graphics require a GPU present? I am wondering whether I can use my existing GPU and put it inside the machine to install the OS and subsequently remove (as I am using it command line only anyway). I would just enable SSH instead.

System would be running on a Ryzen 7 1700X

Comment: Most motherboards wont boot without *any* form of GPU.

Comment: Yes; It’s required